# Proof regarding to Polar Decomposition and Jordan basis

Tags: linear-algebra

> a.) Prove that every invertible matrix A has a *polar decomposition*,
>   written $A = QB$, into the product of an orthogonal matrix $Q$ and a
>   positive definite matrix $B>0$. Show that if $detA>0$, then $Q$ is a
>   proper orthogonal matrix.
>
> c.) Prove that every positive definite matrix $K$ has a unique positive definite *square root.*

How will I be able to prove these?

- **For part a** - I know I must use Gram matrix $K = A^TA$ in order to prove it.
- **For part c** - I do not know what to do.

Comment: How is this question b.) with the Jordan basis? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Berci I dont quite understand your question. Do you mean my attempt at a solution or the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic way for doing a) is to use the singular value decomposition. Then $A=UDV$, with $D$ diagonal with non-negative diagonal entries, and $U,V$ orthogonal. Since $A$ is invertible, $D$ has to be invertible, so it is positive-definite. Now let $Q=UV$, $B=V^*DV$. Then $B$ is positive-definite and $Q$ is orthogonal.

If $\det A>0$, then $\det Q>0$ (since $\det B>0$). So $\det Q=1$.

I have to admit that I cannot understand what is being asked in question b).

As for c), is $K$ is positive-definite then (under the usual assumption that $K$ is symmetric), $K=VDV^*$, with $V$ orthogonal and $D$ diagonal and positive definite. Let $E$ be the diagonal matrix with $E_{kk}=\sqrt{D_{kk}}$. Then $E$ is positive-definite and $E^2=D$. Now put $L=VEV^*$; then $L$ is positive-definite and $L^2=K$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Martin! I will edit out part b. because you and Berci told me the same thing.